# Angular how to bring up the native keyboard on Ipad when user focus on input

Tags: angularjs, ipad, input, keyboard

I have an input box that works fine on computers, but when browsing using ipad, the keyboard doesn't show up, so cannot type in anything. how would i bring up the keyboard upon entering the input box?

Update: I need to tap on the inputbox for a couple seconds, to bring the keyboard up. can there be more sensitive solution? I have ngTouch already and it's 1.3.0